# Magento2 : How to create request a quote and edit the price in cart page?

Tags: magento2

I am a beginner for Magento 2, Now I have to edit the price in cart page. I am struggling to start this. Anyone have an idea for that?

Comment: Frontend customer are not supposed to edit the price at cart page. Admin can edit the product price at Products > Catalog > Edit. Please provide more detaill

Answer (score 0):

To change item price in **cart** either override this template

```
magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/cart/item/default.phtml
```

or override

```
magento/module-checkout/Block/Cart/Item/Renderer.php -> getUnitPriceHtml
```

How to override template:
https://www.classyllama.com/blog/template-override-m2

How to override a class:
[Magento 2 Training Overriding a core class](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91990/magento-2-training-overriding-a-core-class)

As for the second solution it may also impact the prices in checkout, but I believe you will need to change them in the end also :)